# `maxHeight` behaves exactly as `height` frame modifier

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm confused by `frame(maxHeight: ...)` modifier. I would expect that the resulting view would have dynamic height capped at `maxHeight`. However, the height of the view is always `maxHeight`.

In the example below, I wanted the green rectangle to have `30px` and the red one should fill the rest space. However, there's additional padding between the rectangles caused by `maxHeight` modifier.

Is there any other way to achieve what I want?
`maxHeight` seems useless to me know. It's pretty much the same as using `height`, isn't it?

**Code**

```swift
var body: some View {
   VStack(spacing: 0) {
      Color.green
         .frame(height: 30)
         .frame(maxHeight: 60, alignment: .top)
            
      Color.red
   }
   .frame(height: 100)
   .background(Color.black)
}
```

**Preview:**

[image]

Comment: ... too many words - moved into answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every modifier can (in general!) create a new view. So, you create at first green view unlimited, then limit it by 30px (so green filled that space), and then create another view with 60px (and because there is no stopper it filled that available space)... and then everything with red view below(!) considered above views. To get what you expected just remove .frame(maxHeight - it is not needed here.

... but, if you still want (for any reason) to keep it and fulfil expectation, then it is a matter for layout order - give a preference to second view, like

```
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        Color.green
            .frame(height: 30)
            .frame(maxHeight: 60, alignment: .top)

        Color.red
            .layoutPriority(1)   // << here !!
    }
```

and you get

[image: demo]